# AngularFire 2 sendPasswordResetEmail

Tags: typescript, angular, angularfire2

I want to implement a reset password / forgot password function with AngularFire2. It seems like the function sendPasswordResetEmail is not yet provided by AngularFire2 or the typings are not updated. Since  sendPasswordResetEmail is part of AngularFireAuth, I thought I still could access the function like this:

```
(this.af.auth as any).sendPasswordResetEmail('email').
        then((result: any) => {
            console.log('Result:', result);
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            console.log('Err:', err);
        });
```

Typescript gives me this error:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

Since I am new to typescript + angular2, any hints how I can access the sendPasswordResetEmail ?. My guess is that I have to access the pure js sdk provided by firebase, but I dont know how.

Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  I don't think angularfire 2.0.0 beta.2 as this yet.

Answer (score 6):

You may be able to use the existing but not fully implemented functionalities of AngularFire2 SDK by Injecting `FirebaseApp` in your component constructor as seen below. This will give you access to the `sendPasswordResetEmail` method:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-forgot-password',
   template: '...'
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent {
  private auth: any;
  constructor(private af : AngularFire, @Inject(FirebaseApp) fa : any) {
    this.auth = fa.auth();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.user.email)
        .then( resp => console.log('sent!') )
        .catch( error => console.log('failed to send', error) );
  }
}
```

Notice that you will have to declare your instance of `FirebaseApp` as `any` for now.

Comment: FYI, you can declare the injected app as `firebase.app.App` - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39069813/6680611) answer.

Comment: Great @cartant ! Thanks.