# Accessing firebase.storage() with AngularFire2 (Angular2 rc.5)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am trying to access firebase.storage() on my project, with:

- "@angular": "2.0.0-rc.5"
- "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.3-pre2"
- "firebase": "^3.3.0"

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593188/firebase-storage-and-angularfire2), and created my .component.ts file with:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var firebase : any;

@Component({
  template: '<img [src]="image">'
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  image: string;
  constructor() {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
}
```

and I get the following error in the browser console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./bstorageComponent class FBStorageComponent_Host - inline template:0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp().
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp().
```

but, I initialised firebase in app.module.ts with this import

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

I'm not getting what I'm missing. How can I access storage using firebase? I have no problem with accessing database with angularfire2.
Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Internally, AngularFire2 calls Firebase's `initializeApp` in a DI factory when creating its `FirebaseApp`.

You are seeing the error because you are accessing the global `firebase` instance and `initializeApp` has not yet been called - as the DI infrastructure has not needed to create `FirebaseApp` or any of its dependencies.

Rather than using the global `firebase`, you could inject `FirebaseApp` (which is the value returned by Firebase's `initializeApp` function):

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  template: '<img [src]="image">'
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  image: string;
  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: any) {
    const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
}
```

And, as it's no longer required, you could delete `declare var firebase : any;`.

---

Early versions of the Firebase NPM module did not include typings. Recent versions now include them, so the `firebaseApp` property could be strongly typed like this:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  template: '<img [src]="image">'
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  image: string;
  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
}
```

---

With the refactoring that accompanied the [version 4 release candidate](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/855) of AngularFire2, `FirebaseApp` is no longer a token, so the injection can be simplified:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import 'firebase/storage';

@Component({
  template: '<img [src]="image">'
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  image: string;
  constructor(firebaseApp: FirebaseApp) {
    const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
}
```

However, an explicit import of `firebase/storage` is required because AngularFire2 now imports only the portions of the Firebase API that it uses. (Note that there is a proposal for [storage support](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/963).)

Comment: Why do I have a feeling this is the best way to drop down to the Firebase SDK? Ooh yeah, because it is! Thank you so much, everywhere I turn, everyone says `declare var firebase: any;` but that doesn't work. Thank you again.

Comment: This is gold. Thxs

Comment: That code didn't work for me as it is. I had to add a variable `fb: firebase.app.App;` to the component, and in the constructor I assigned the injected `FirebaseApp` to it.
`constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    this.fb = firebaseApp;
  }`
Of course, then whenever I need to use it: `this.fb....`

Comment: @adail.retamal As written, `firebaseApp` is a constructor parameter and can be used only in the constructor itself. If you want to use it outside of the constructor there is a terse alternative: just add either `public` or `private` and it will be declared as a member. E.g. `constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) private firebaseApp: firebase.app.App)` and, outside of the constructor, access it using `this.firebaseApp`.

Comment: @cartant You are right! I did that because I was getting compilation errors on Angular4. I have uninstalled (`npm uninstall firebase angularfire2 --save`) and reinstalled (`npm install firebase angularfire2 --save`) both firebase and angularfire2, and now it works as you say. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The above code no longer works, I keep getting 'firebase.storage is not a function', try adding the following code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
```