# How to inject FirebaseApp in Angular2 service to use firebase.storage() with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 version 2.0.0-beta.6

I wrote a `database.service` with AngularFire injection (see extract database service code).

It's ok for my usage.

But now I'd like to integrate usage of Firebase storage() API. But I can't Inject FirebaseApp in constructor's service as I use in component like this :

```
constructor( @Inject(FirebaseApp) private firebaseApp: any) {}
```

Extract of database service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseApp, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    this.init();
  }
... some service function

}
```

Some help, please.
  Laurent

Comment: Does `import {Injectable,Inject} from '@angular/core'` correct the error?

Comment: @The FORCE JB Yes with Inject added that's correct my problem. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing firebase.storage() with AngularFire2 (Angular2 rc.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067832/accessing-firebase-storage-with-angularfire2-angular2-rc-5)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to initialize the `AngularFireModule` in your Angular  module

```js
imports: [
  ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseApp),
  ...
]
```

and then all the you can inject directly all the sub services, like `AngularFireAuth` or `AngularFireStorage`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
    ...
  }
... the rest of your code

}
```

I hope that helps