# Create or increment a value with Angular2/AngularFire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm using Angular 2 and AngularFire 2 to interact with Firebase.  In Firebase I have a tags collection.  I'd like to either create or increment the number for a tag.  The code I'm using looks something like this:

```js
let tagName = "angular";
let tagObs = this.af.database.object(`/tags/${tagName}`);
tagObs.subscribe(function(snapshot) {
    let newValue = (snapshot.$value) ? (snapshot.$value + 1) : 1;
    this.tagObs.set(newValue);
}.bind({ tagObs: tagObs ));
```

It's not clear to me why, but this doesn't work.  It creates an infinite loop that just keeps incrementing the tag value.

Using AngularFire 2, how should I go about either creating or incrementing a value for a node (a "tag" in this case)?

### Update after @Fiddle's comment

Here is the same code with a "fat arrow" function.  The same problem exists... an infinite loop.

```js
let tagName = "angular";
let tagObs = this.af.database.object(`/tags/${tagName}`);
tagObs.subscribe((snapshot) => {
    let newValue = (snapshot.$value) ? (snapshot.$value + 1) : 1;
    tagObs.set(newValue);
});
```

### Update # 2: the code that worked

Just for the sake of clarity, this is the actual code I ended up using:

```js
let tagObs = this.af.database.object(`/tags/${tagName}`);
tagObs.transaction(function(currentCount) {
  return currentCount + 1;
});
```

Comment: start by converting the subscribe callback to an arrow function, otherwise the context will change for `this`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Fiddles.  However, converting to the use of a "fat arrow" function doesn't change the behavior.  It is essentially the same thing, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Using an arrow function won't make a difference; you'd already used `bind` with an appropriate context. The issue is the observable emits a new value with each change, so your calling `set` effects a change and results in the infinite loop. You could use the RxJS `first` operator to ensure the observable emits only once and then completes, but, really, what you are doing would be better suited to using the underlying Firebase API's [`transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) function.

Comment: @cartant: Thanks, that makes sense.  I've read up on the Firebase JavaScript SDK's `transaction` method, but this doesn't appear to be a part of AngularFire 2's wrapper API.  I could use the JS SDK directly, however the current user in my system needs to be authenticated to read/write the tags. I've handled authentication using AngularFire 2.  It's unclear to me how to go about using the JS SDK directly in tandem with the authentication logic from AngularFire 2.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39069813/6680611) shows how to get access to the SDK's app when using AngularFire2.

Comment: I'd forgotten that the public `$ref` property had been recently introduced. Using `transaction` as in the answer below would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, @cartant.  Yep, the `$ref` solution in @adriancarriger's solution worked.  But, I really appreciate your help.  And the constructor argument in your other answer you linked to is interesting `@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: firebase.app.App`.  I still have a lot of Angular 2/ Typescript stuff to learn.  :)  Cheers.

Comment: my solution of angularfire2 V5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130381/1782745).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Infinite loop

You got an infinite loop because the `subscribe` method is called every time the `tagObs`reference receives a new value, and the subscribe function changes the value of `tabObs` with the `set` method.

## Firebase Transactions

Firebase provides a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) method for this situation. This is really helpful because:

> `transaction()` is used to modify the existing value to a new value, ensuring there are no conflicts with other clients writing to the same location at the same time.

```
tagObs.$ref.transaction(tagValue => {
  return tagValue ? tagValue + 1 : 1;
});
```

It's important to note that this is a method from the Firebase API (not Angularfire2), but you can still access those methods by calling `$ref` on your provided `tagObs` which looks like a `FirebaseObjectObservable`.

Comment: Ah, that's the ticket. :)  Using `$ref` worked. Thanks, @adriancarriger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hadn't seen how to user firebase API when including angularfire. I have tried your suggestion but get the following two error messages, is there anything you can suggest here please?  `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: set` and  `Unhandled Promise rejection: set ; Zone: angular ; Task: WebSocket.addEventListener:message ; Value: Error: set`

Comment: my angularfire2 V5 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130381/1782745