# angularfire2 best way to increment a value?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angular2-services, angularfire2

I searched in many forums, questions, in [doc](https://www.firebase.com) but can't find the correct solution.

### Problem

What is the best way to increment a value using angularfire2 ?
I saw we could use [transaction()][] but it's not for angularfire2 actually.
Or with snapshot ?

user.service.ts

```
incrementLike(userToIncrementLike){
    this.af.database.object('users/' + userToIncrementLike.uid).subscribe((userObject) => {
      var newUser = {
        likes: userObject.likes + 1
        };

     });
     this.af.database.object('users/' + userToIncrementLike.uid).update(newUser);

  }
```

I tried also in this way :

```
incrementLike(userToIncrementLike){

    let obs = this.af.database.object('users/' + userToIncrementLike.uid);
    obs.subscribe((snapshot) => {
      let newValue = (snapshot.$value) ? (snapshot.$value + 1) : 1;
      obs.set(newValue);
    });
  }
```

Thank you very much for your help and tips :) 
Luis.

Comment: what you are describing doesn't exactly make sense.  The number of likes becomes *exactly* `1340` or something similar? and does your `console.log` fire 1340 times?

Comment: Yeah so I checked and modified my question : it increments exactly 1321 times so 1321...2642.. and in console it's called also 1321 times. I updated the probable solution as well. :)

Comment: Alright I solved my problem :D Thank you anyway !

Comment: @luiswill Please provide your solution as a separate answer. Self-answers are encouraged on Stack Overflow and provide a good way to build your reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't necessary to define an object or to use the `update()` method. The object already exists in the database, so you can just work on it there. This is actually the purpose of `transaction()`--[to work on the data at the data location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction) and therefore prevent conflicts; e.g., two users updating the same value at the same time.

You can also use the template literal in your path if you like. :) (Note the backticks instead of single quotes.)

```
incrementLike(userToIncrementLike){
    this.af.database.object(`users/${userToIncrementLike.uid}/likes`).query
    .ref.transaction(likes => {
        if (likes === null) {
            return likes = 1;
        } else {
            return likes + 1;
        }
    })
}
```

Update: September, 2019. Use `query` instead of `$ref`.

Comment: Yes your code works perfectly ! At the beginning I thought you couldn't use transaction because it's a function from the Firebase SDK and not angularfire2... but with .$ref you can do it :) Thank you !

Comment: which version is it?

Answer (score 15):

Firestore now has `increment()` which correctly increments a field even if multiple users are competing to edit at the same time

[Incrementing Values Atomically with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html)

To use this in angularfire2

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';

incrementLike(userToIncrementLike) {
    const increment = firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
    const userLike = this.af.doc(`users/${userToIncrementLike.uid}`);
    userLike.update({ likes: increment });
}
```

I used firestore directly since I couldn't find `FieldValue` in angularfire2.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, seeing that it is the most current

Answer (score 5):

"angularfire2 V5" Solution:

```
incrementLike(userToIncrementLike){
this.af.database.object(`users/${userToIncrementLike.uid}/likes`)
  .query.ref.transaction((likes => {
    if (likes === null) {
        return likes = 1;
    } else {
        return likes + 1;
    }
})};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Angular 14:**

With the latest version you can use increment function straight from @angular/fire

```
import { increment } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

and then

```
this.firestore.doc("users/"+$id).update({count: increment(1)});
```

Answer (score 0):

@angular/fire (Angular version 7)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

```
incrementLike(userToIncrementLike) {

  //VARIABLE FOR MANAGING THE SCOPE
  var that = this;
  this.afs.firestore.collection("users").where("id", "==", userToIncrementLike.uid)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {

     querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

        return that.afs.firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
           // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
           return transaction.get(doc.ref).then(function(doc) {
              if (!doc.exists) {
                 throw "Document does not exist!";
              }

              //THIS IS WHERE TO DO THE INCREMENT
              var new_score = doc.data().score + 1;
              transaction.update(doc.ref, { score: new_score });
           });
        }).then(function() {
           console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
        }).catch(function(error) {
           console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
        });

     });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it on Firestore. This same code use to practically work on realtime DB.

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2"

const login = this.afs.doc(`/users/${uid}`);
    login.valueChanges()
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((user: User) => {
            login.update({ login: user.login as number + 1 });
        });
```