# How to use arrayUnion in Firestore using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to learn using Firestore and could not find the documentation helpful at all in the case AngularFire since using FieldValue just throws an error as "FieldValue does not exist".

```
const userRef = this.firestore.collection('users').doc(email);

userRef.update({
  lessonsWatched: this.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newLessonObject)
})
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { arrayUnion } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
this.firestore.doc(...).update({ field: arrayUnion(...) });
```

Similar should work for other FieldValue functions, such as `increment`.

See:

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2036#issuecomment-1337755616
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74691835