# Increment a value inside Firebase document using AngularFire2 @angular/fire V5

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have a document in Firebase with a value that I want to increment but I don't see anything in the documentation for Angularfire2 on how to do this.

I tried using this answer [Create or increment a value with Angular2/AngularFire2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795605/create-or-increment-a-value-with-angular2-angularfire2/40799771) but fail because my this.db instance does not recognize the object method.

** UPDATE **

I was able to somewhat get my code to do what I want by doing the following:

```
incrementChoice(choiceKey) {
    this.db.doc(choiceKey).valueChanges().subscribe((choice:any) => {
      this.db.doc(`choices/${choiceKey}`)
        .update({
          votes: ++choice.votes
        });
    })
  }
```

The problem, however, is that I am now stuck in an infinite loop of incrementing because each time the value is incrementing the subscription kicks in and increments again. I don't know how else to get the choice vote value? Can someone help me refactor this so that I can obtain just one choice object using its key and not be bounded to the subscription when I update the value of the votes?

I understand that it's possible to get the object by fetching the entire collection but for my use case, I do not want to have to depend on the whole collection to get the object and votes value from that object. I already have the object Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
this.afs.doc(`choices/${choice.key}`)
  .update({
    votes: ++choice.votes
  });
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cloud-firestore?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Cannot find name 'choice'. What should choice refer to in this example? Also, will the update function take into account collisions between different clients updating at the same time?

Comment: Ummm. Actually that was just an example to show you how you can update a Document if you have the Document Object already. If you check my sample stackBlitz, you'll see that I already have the `valuation` objects, and I'm just updating the votes property on them based on the user's click.

Comment: It looks like that worked. Thanks! Do you know if this is comparable to using the transaction in the firebase docs? Originally I planned to use a transaction to guard against different clients trying to increment at the same time.

Comment: Also, do you know how I can get the document without attaching a snapShot or valueChange listener? Currently when I increment it gets stuck in an infinite loop because I am incrementing inside the snapShot code block

Comment: The previous example that I had shared, does it by getting the value of the complete collection. And then based on the item that is clicked, the value for a particular document is updated.

Comment: what if I don't have a collection though? what if it's only one document? still struggling to just get one item

Comment: Just have a look at my `ngOnInit` implementation of the AppComponent. I'm getting the voteObject right there.

Once I have the vote Object, I'll also have the `id` of it. I can then update that vote Object using the `id` by creating a reference to the document and then calling the `update` method on it as I've done in the above code snippet.

Comment: in the example you posted you're using the collection to get the individual object. i don't see how to get just the object without going through a collection first

Comment: I updated the question to reflect where I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it working with the following (thanks @SiddAjmera for helping me get on the right track):

```
  incrementChoice(choiceKey) {
    const choiceDoc:any = this.db.collection('choices').doc(choiceKey);
    choiceDoc.ref.get().then(choice => {
      let votes = choice.data().votes
      choiceDoc.update({
        votes: ++votes
      });
    });
```