# Retrieving images from Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-storage, observable, firebase-storage

I'm creating a chat app in **Angular 4** where people can send chat messages (text) and media. I'm using **Firebase** to store all conversations, messages and members. And it's **Cloud Storage** to store files.

I've already stored some messages with media (images) attached to them, but I'm not able to load these images in the conversation view.

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files I'd be able to download these files via:

```
const storageRef = this.firebaseApp.storage().ref().child(message.media.path + message.media.filename);
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => console.log(url));
```

Which does work, since I can see the url in the console output, and clicking on it shows me my uploaded image.

**Example output url:**

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<databasename>.appspot.com/o/messages%2Fconversation1%2Fmessage1%2Fmedia%2F91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg?alt=media&token=<sometoken>
```

My question is how I can show this one in my message.component.html template.
I've tried the following:

> Attempt 1:

**message.component.html:**

```
<img src="{{message.media?.url}}">
```

**chat.service.ts:**

```
public retrieveMessages(conversationId) {
    this.messages = this.db.list('messages/' + conversationId, {query: {limitToLast: 10}});
    this.messages.subscribe(messages => {
        this.appendMessagesWithMediaURL(messages);
    });
}

public appendMessagesWithMediaURL(messages) {
    for (const message of messages) {
        if (message.media) { // message has media
            this.firebaseApp.storage().ref().child(message.media.path + message.media.filename).getDownloadURL().then(url => message.media.url = url);
        }
    }
}
```

*This will set all 'src' attributes to 'unknown'. I think this is because the .url property does not exist when the view loads (messages will be retrieved first, THEN we declare and initialize the .url property).*

> Attempt 2:

**message.component.html:**

```
<img src="{{(chatService.getMediaURL(message) | async)}}">
```

**chat.service.ts:**

```
public getMediaURL(message) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        if (message.media) {
            const storageRef = this.firebaseApp.storage().ref().child(message.media.path + message.media.filename);
            storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => observer.next(url));
        }
    });
}
```

*This makes my Angular app hang when I load the message.component. (RAM usage is >1GB in a few seconds and the tab isn't responding anymore.) Note that I'm only loading 10 messages, only 2 of them do have a media property with 1 single image (200KB each).*

> Additional info

**Firebase layout:**

```
"messages": {
    "conversation1": {
        "message1": {
            "content": "Hello World",
            "media": {
                "path": "/messages/conversation1/message1/",
                "filename": "picture.png",
                "type": "image/jpeg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example that I used as reference for 'how to retrieve images': [Accessing firebase.storage() with AngularFire2 (Angular2 rc.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067832/accessing-firebase-storage-with-angularfire2-angular2-rc-5)

**Fragment of conversation.component.html**

```
<!-- BEGIN Conversation  !-->
<div class="chat-inner" id="my-conversation">
    <!-- BEGIN Message  !-->
        <chassis-message *ngFor="let message of chatService.messages | async" [message]="message"></chassis-message>
    <!-- END Message  !-->
</div>
<!-- BEGIN Conversation  !-->
```

**Fragment of message.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../chat.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'chassis-message',
    templateUrl: './message.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./message.component.css'],
})
export class MessageComponent {
    @Input() message: any;

    constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
    }
}
```

> Question

What is the correct way to retrieve those images?

Comment: why dont you save the url in a component variable by calling to the service like in a image variable and then access it in the component template using elvis i:e safe operator or ngIf

Comment: I don't have variables in the component besides an @Input variable for the message. This is a fragment of my conversation.component.html.

<chassis-message *ngFor="let message of chatService.messages | async" [message]="message"></chassis-message>

Comment: but you can add right and make the html template simplier instead of adding a method call in it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly... If you think you know an answer, please post an answer (not a comment) with a piece of code how you would solve this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

In message.component.ts, create a simple method (getMediaURL) which will call the chatservice and save the url like so:

```
private url;

constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
    this.getMediaURL('/messages/awesome.jpg');
}

private getMediaURL(imageRef) {
    const that = this;
    this.chatService.getMediaURL(imageRef).then(url => that.url = url);
}
```

Update your html to reflect the change:

```
<img [src]="url">
```

Then add the required method to the chat.service.ts:

```
public getMediaURL(image): firebase.Promise<any> {
    const storageRef = this.firebaseApp.storage().ref().child(image);
    return storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log('firebase response: ' + url);
        return url;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This suits my needs :)
Only thing that I had to add was generating the imageRef by concatenating the message.media.path and message.media.folder, and since these do not exist when executing the constructor method, I call this in the ngOnChanges now.

The initial problem was that when calling the method 'getMediaURL' in the template it keeps calling it.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i would like you to do this might solve the issue.

like in the example of accessing firebase storage. In the component you store the image url . here they are doing it in the constructor.

```
 url:yourobject;
 constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: any) {
    const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
```

Now in the template you can access the url or the image like this

{{url?.image}}

or if it is the url you are directly getting make use of ngIf

```
<div *ngIf = "url">
   {{url}}
</div>
```

Comment: If you mean by 'in the component' in the message.component.ts, I tried that, but I cant use this.message in its constructor since this.message is undefined at that time. See http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqon2/2.

Comment: As it is a service call it it will take some time make use of ngif or safe operator there

Comment: It fails in the class, not the template

Comment: Usr that in the template instead of class the url will be used some where in template right?